# Detecting change in focus of webpage using Flash

Tags: flash, web-applications

I wanted to design a website to take quiz.Main functionality i needed is to restrict user from changing the tab or opening new browser or any window so that user cannot cheat at least by using internet or some ebook.I play a game Hozzat cricket on fb that easily detects change in focus when i change the tab or open new window in the middle of the game.I want to know how is this done and how can i use the same in my web-based quiz application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this: http://www.wuup.co.uk/as3-basics-detect-flash-window-focus-with-actionscript-30

windowNotActive event listeners